# Angular UI Router states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states. One state is a table with domains and the second state is information about a domain. The table has filters (dropdown selects, dropdown checkboxes) that can be applied to the table data. You can click into the domain from the table that triggers the second state (state1.domain).

My question is when I click away from state1 into state1.domain and then click back to state1 how can i preserve my filtered data and not reinitialize the controller? Currently, when I click back to state1 my filters have been cleared and so is the table data.

```
$stateProvider
.state ('state1', {
    url: '/state1',
    views: {
        "main@": {
            controller: 'StateOneCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'folder/state1.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    ncyBreadcrumb: { label: 'State One' },
    data: { pageTitle: 'State One', showTitle: false}
})
.state('state1.domain', {
    url: '/:domain',
    views: {
        "main@": {
            controller: 'StateOneDomainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'folder/state1-domain.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    ncyBreadcrumb: { label: '{{domain}}' },
    data: { pageTitle: 'State One Domain', showTitle: false }
})
```

Comment: Its bit similar as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542972/how-to-persist-optional-parameter-on-browser-back-in-ui-router only you are using `data` option of state and I'm using `params`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using breadcrumbs to navigate back.

Comment: in any case those values doesn't preserved by `ui-router`, you need to maintain in service/factory

Comment: @PankajParkar Yup, the service/factory way is an other really good option that i forgot to mention.

Comment: @Okazari yes I know..I had mentioned that in my question.. I'm going to put bounty on my question after 27 mins.. I want other way on it.

Comment: Just found this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1158 about the "notify" attribute that could be set to false to prevent events (such as reloading controller) but it is actually not working (bug).

Comment: Thanks, for now I'll just hack a service in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Services

You can store theses values in a service. On your controller initialization you will just set up the controllers var with the stored var in the service.

May be the best solution.

### Using session storage

In my opinion one of the way to go is by using the session storage to store the filters within a navigation flow into you application.

In you controller your will init the filters vars like this :

```
$scope.filterName = sessionStorage.filterName
```

On each filter change you will save to sessionStorage the value

```
//In your HTML on the filter
ng-change="onFilterNameChange()"

//In your JS
$scope.onFilterNameChange = function(){
    sessionStorage.filterName = $scope.filterName
}
```

And that's pretty much all.

If you want to be able to "clean" the filters you could also do this you could manage an optional url param (like ?resetFilters=true) that clean the filters.

### Using query params

You could also (if there is not that much filters) explicitly sets the filters in the URL like this

```
.state ('state1', {
    url: '/state1?filter1&filter2&filter3',
    views: {
        "main@": {
            controller: 'StateOneCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'folder/state1.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    ncyBreadcrumb: { label: 'State One' },
    data: { pageTitle: 'State One', showTitle: false}
})
```

But you may be stuck as you can't give an object to the URL (whereas you can stringify one for your sessionStorage.

Hope it helped.

Comment: what if there are 10 filter parameter? will it be good solution to pass it through url?

Comment: @PankajParkar Depends on the tastes. I'd prefer not to give 10 filter in my URL (wheras Google pretty much give all the informations in the url) If i had that much filters i would go for the sessionStorage solution.

Comment: local storage might be one way to handle this. I was also considering using a service to hold the state of the filters when the user navigated between states since my biggest issue is the controller reinitializes itself when the user clicks back to state1.

Comment: @ibtjw In my opinion sessionStorage (not localStorage) is a way to go. But the service is a really really good option too if not better.

Comment: Right, session storage not local storage. :)

Comment: Do you need an exemple about the service way or is it fine for you if i just mention it ?

Comment: I already started writing the service, thanks. :) It just seems odd that ui-router doesn't have any kind of mechanism that will hold a state for you if you click away, or to preserve the controllers state.

Comment: @ibtjw Didn't realize it before but you've both right. Maybe we should argue a bit more on this thread https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2115

Comment: @Okazari If you add any comment on that thread would help others who are facing this issue... I don't think so its implementation issue in any sense..

Comment: @ibtjw if you are little more worried about the issue the you could also add an comment..I already updated my issue by adding your question too..